# Reading a CSV with Highchart

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm struggling to output a line chart from my CSV file, I get the graph but not data in the graph, could someone please tell me what is wrong with the code below?

The data in the CSV is formatted like so:

```
26-04-2012 09:10,0
26-04-2012 09:20,0
26-04-2012 09:30,0
26-04-2012 09:40,0
26-04-2012 09:50,0
26-04-2012 10:00,1
26-04-2012 10:10,1
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var c = [];
        var d = [];

        $.get('test.csv', function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                c.push(items[0]);
                d.push(parseInt(items[1]));
            });
        });
        var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'reading'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Date Measurement'
                    },
                    categories: c
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'reading'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: d
                }]
        };

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="chart" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `$.get` call will return immediately and as a result you will create the chart before the `test.csv` is downloaded (containing no data at all).

The callback function that you pass to `$.get` will run when the file is downloaded so placing the creation of the chart there would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The chart is loaded with no data because the csv file is loaded after the chart, because the get request takes time to receive a response. The following will load the data from your file and display the chart after the file loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
                      <html>
                      <head>
                      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var c = [];
        var d = [];
        var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'reading'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Date Measurement'
                    },
                    categories: c
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'reading'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: d
                }]
        };

        var jqxhr = $.get('test.csv', function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                c.push(items[0]);
                d.push(parseInt(items[1]));
            })
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
    });
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="chart" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```